# Looking for technical information for direct/reverse spherification with alcohol

Tags: food-science, alcohol, spherification

I am trying to create alcohol spheres ranging in ABV from 10% to 40%. Reverse spherification seems like the ideal option because I want the spheres to have that pop feeling and have the liquid come out. Being able to store them is pretty essential too. The ideal sphere diameter is 4 mm to 6 mm. Although I have read that reverse primarily makes larger spheres. My questions are:

What is the smallest sphere you can make with reverse? (Any pictures would be helpful)

How do you make the smallest spheres possible with reverse?

If I have to use direct to get smaller spheres, how long will the interior of the spheres stay liquid?

If I store direct spheres and they do gel, will the spheres still have the same alcohol content when they solidify?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of the process, and have only done it a couple of times, but I've read plenty about it.  As I understand it, I think higher than 20% ABV will interfere with the gelling process. You will have to experiment. I've seen as small as a millimeter or two with reverse...a bit larger with direct.  For direct you need the outer layer to be thick enough to hold the shape. For small spheres you will want a pipette. I would store in the alcohol that you are making them from.  The final result is going to vary a lot depending on the alcohol you are using. If the product has a lot of volatiles, expect those to dissipate rather quickly.  In my experience, spherification is a flavor and aroma thief.  I don't have any references for you but the internet is full of them, as I am sure you know.